# ExtJS 5 load existing store with local data

Tags: extjs

I am doing unit testing and would like to add dummy data to an existing store.  In the function I am testing, I am calling a store:

```
var tripStore = Ext.getStore('Trips');
```

Normally, this store would have been populated by an Ajax call at a previous point.  However, since I am testing I want to use dummy data and not rely on the back end.  I realize I could rewrite the function to pass in the store, but I do not want to rewrite this for the sake of testing.

Bottom line, how do I add local data to a store that already exists but has no data in it? Furthermore, the back end is not available, so when I try store.load or store.reload it throws a 404 saying it cannot find the url rest/trip.  I don't want it to try and call this url, but instead I want to add local data.

The model definition:

```
Ext.define('app.model.Trip', {
    fields:[
        {name: 'someField1', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'someField2', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'someField3', type: 'string'},
    ],
    proxy: {
        noCache: true,
        url: 'rest/trip',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'trips'
        }
    }
});
```

The (attempted) test script that is calling the url when I don't want it to, but only want it to add the local data:

```
var tripsStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Trips');
tripsStore.load({
    autoLoad: false,
    addRecords: true,
    proxy: {
        data: localData,
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            debugger
        } else {
            debugger
        }
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ajax.SimManager`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ux.ajax.SimManager). See [`example`](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-associations) (open Details on the right-hand side, click on any of the Data tabs).